# Авторизация на сайте через Web Form Aplications

Tags: c#, авторизация

Всем привет! Нужно выполнить автоматический логин на сайте при помощи Web Form Aplication на C#.

Есть ссылка http://mywebsite.com

Сама форма

```
<div id="formul">
<form onsubmit="return validateLoginForm(this)&amp;&amp; JustOneClick(this)" action="/do/login" method="post" name="loginForm">
<div id="deja">Уже внесено</div>
<table id="login">
<tbody><tr>
<td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value='';javascript:this.style.color='#000000';this.onfocus = function(){};" onclick="this.value='';javascript:this.style.color='#000000';this.onclick = function(){};" value="логин" maxlength="10" id="username" name="userid" class="id"></td>
<td><input type="text" onfocus="this.value='';replaceT(this);" onclick="this.value='';replaceT(this);" value="пароль" maxlength="10" id="password" name="password" class="id"></td>
<td><div id="fle_conx"><input type="submit" id="btsubmit" value="Подключение" class="conx"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<div id="prem_visite">1-е обращение? Создать счет</div>
<div id="oubli"><a href="/do/recupCodesConnexion">Забыли пароль</a>
</div>
<div id="insc"><a href="/do/inscription">Регистрация</a>
</div>
<div id="souvenir"><input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="souvenir">&nbsp;Запомнить меня
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="jbnhPb2DDcnF72ebHm" name="window">
</form>
</div>
```

И сама форма авторизации, можно наглядный пример?

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотели сказать, Web Forms Application. В Windows Forms нет тегов.

Answer (score 0):

Привожу пример кода, он не работает для того сайта, но поменять его легко можно и для вашего сайта.

```
webBrowser web = new webBroswer();
web.load('тут адресс странички');

foreach(HTMLElement elem in web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
{
  if(elem.getAttrinbute("name") == "username")
  {
    elem.SetAttribute("value", "тут логин");
  }

  if(elem.getAttrinbute("name") == "password")
  {
    elem.SetAttribute("value", "тут пароль");
  }

  if(elem.getAttrinbute("name") == "login")
  {
    elem.InvokeMember("click");
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы сами модифицировали код, если что